# Why uvicorn cannot be found if a volume is specified in docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm setting up a fastapi compose.yaml file for development.

Here the simplified layout of my project:

[image]

Dockerfile -> size optimized: 170MB

```
    # The builder image, used to build the virtual environment
    FROM python:3.11-bullseye as builder
    
    # Install package manager
    RUN pip install poetry==1.7.1
    
    # Define environment
    ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
        POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
        POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
        POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache
    
    # Set work directory
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Copy project dependencies
    COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
    # Install production dependencies only and remove poetry cache directory
    RUN poetry install --without dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR
    
    # The runtime image, used to run the service
    FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye as runtime
    
    # Set virtual environment path and add it to the system Path
    ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv \
        PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"
    
    # Copy project dependencies from builder stage
    COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
    
    # Copy project code
    COPY app/ /app/
    
    # Run service
    CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

The layout generated in the debian container is the same, so everything is okay, when I run the container it deploys a fastapi server that works perfect!

I want to create a development environment that watch my code and reloads the server in every change.

For that I created the following compose.yaml:

```
    services:
      api:
        image: pws
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
          # - ./app/:/app   # I have tried many combinations of this line
          - ./app/:/app/
        command: ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]
```

The issue is that running "docker compose up" goes well when "volumes" are not specified, but at the moment I try to include it, breaks:

**Error:**
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Answer (score 1):

On the host you have `.venv` in your root directory, but in your Dockerfile it's `app/.venv`, so when you mount `app` from host there is no `.venv` in the container

To resolve it in your Dockerfile you should move `.venv` to `/.venv`(or anywhere outside of `/app`) from `/app/.venv`

Comment: Good point, I suspected the same and reviewed if inside the container the .venv dissapeared but it stays there. However that should be the conflict, thank you so much!

Comment: @SantiagoOrtizCeballos How did you checked `it stays there`?

Comment: I executed a bash process while the container was running (docker exec -it container_name bash), then I just checked the content of the container using "ls -a"

Comment: Can you add output from `docker exec -it container_name ls -la /app` to the question or somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workarround using [docker compose watch](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/), but still curious about what is happening with bind mounts using "volumes"

```
services:
  api:
    image: pws
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: pws
    environment:
      - WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING=true
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./app/
          target: /app/
          ignore:
            - .venv/
    command: ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]
```